# Coordinating the launch of containers in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have three services (db,app1,app2) and two VM's(dockervm1,dockervm2). Using swarm mode I have spawned db and app1 on vm1 and app2 on vm2.

When db container starts, it creates a database. Now I want to start the service app1 and app2 after db is created and data is populated. I tried setting db as a dependency for app1 and app2. However, the db container is considered to be created as soon as the container starts and not when the actual database is created. So app1 and app2 gets going shortly after db is created.

Is there way to tell docker to consider db container started only once it is done creating all the required tables?
Is there a way the db container can create a file to signal that it is done creating the tables and make the file available to app1 and app2 even if they are on different VMs?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a script in your app containers that cycles until the database is available.  E.g., something like:

```
while ! mysql -u dbuser -p secretpassword -e 'select 1 from sometable' mydb; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Only start the application after the `while` loop exits.

Alternatively, if you are the application developer, just include the necessary retry logic in the application itself.